# Prove that $p|1+2(p-3)!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that  $p|1+2(p-3)!$

I know the wilson's theorem and started with that but I reach a stage where I am not able to solve.

$1+(p-1)!= M(p)$

$=1+(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)!= M(p)$

$=1+ (p^{2}-3p+2)(p-3)! =M(p)$

**After the fault being pointed out, I understand how to solve it.**

Thanks!

Comment: The assertion is false when $p=3$.

Comment: It isn't valid for $p=3$

Comment: Apparently the question in the workbook was wrong. I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you mean for prime $p>2.$ Presumably , by $2 (p-3)!$ you mean $(p-3)!\cdot 2.$

1. False for $p=2,$ as $(-1)!$ is undefined.
2. For odd prime $p,$ we have $(p-1)(p-2)\equiv 2 \not \equiv 0 \pmod p.$ So modulo  $p$ we have $0\equiv 1+(p-3)!\cdot 2\iff$ $ 0\equiv (p-1)(p-2)(1+(p-3)!\cdot 2)\iff$ $\iff 0\equiv (p-1)(p-2)+(p-1)!\cdot 2\iff$ $ 0\equiv 2(1+(p-1)!).$

Answer (score 3):

Answer to original question, which has been changed:

It is not true.  For example $3 \not | 1+3!=7$.  For any $p \ge 3, p$ will divide $(2p-3)!$, so will have remainder $1$ when dividing $1+(2p-3)!$.